# Are bell peppers with brown seeds safe to eat?

Tags: food-safety, bell-peppers

Sometimes when cooking with bell peppers, the seeds on the inside are brown (instead of white). What causes this, and are the peppers safe to eat?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick google brought [this](http://forums.seedsavers.org/forum/gardening/seed-saving/3857-some-of-my-pepper-seeds-are-brown-are-they-okay):

> In this case, the brown ones may have been closest to mature or
>   viable. When fully ripe, most peppers seeds are supposed to be brown
>   or tan. not white.

In my experience, peppers with brown are just old and withered.  They are safe, just not as tasty.  Unless the brown thing is mold, in which case they may be poisonous.

Comment: Commonly seen with some kinds of green chili too.